# Linux cannot kill a PID: invalid signal

Tags: linux, kill, kill-process

IN ubuntu Amazon EC2 instances with root access

when do

```
ps -e
```

The process shows up with a valid PID and process name.  The database table also suggests the process is still ongoing.

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
32194 ?        00:00:00 test
32253 ?        00:00:00 mysql
```

However, any of the following commands kill the process, but returns nothing or "invalid signal".

```
top 
kill
Type in PID
y
returns "invalid signal"
```

or

```
kill -9 PID
kill -s PID
etc.
```

Could any guru enlighten how to deal with the "ghost jobs"?

Comment: what distribution are you on? Easiest to kill a process if nothing works is shutting down the system :D!

Comment: Are you also sure you are using the right pid?

Comment: What kind of a process is it? Is there a lock file? Do you have a PID file? Do you have an init script? Do you use systemd?

Comment: Do you have any resource that is still accessing the process and thus blocking it?

Comment: And lastly, do you have root?

Comment: This might help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work

Comment: Linux questions are better asked over at Unix & Linux or ServerFault

Comment: thanks @mahatmanich.  kill -9 actually works perfectly!

Comment: but you wrote that `kill -9` did not work in your question :-)

Comment: sorry forgot to type "sudo kill -9 PID".  Forgot to mention the "sudo"

Comment: So you did not have root :-) then!

Comment: If I write an answer would you accept it then since my comment mentioned above actually would solve the issue?

Comment: Sure, @mahatmanich!

Comment: please see my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you use the correct rights to kill the process? With root you should be able to kill the process using either:

```
$ su -
# kill -9 PID
```

or

```
$ sudo kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the id of the process, say 32194, I suggest you run:

```
pgrep -l a | grep 32194
```

If the process name has an 'a', the output will show the line and the process name. if not have an 'a', change the letter by other one.

When the process appear, just kill it with:

```
pkill <process name>
```

Comment: Sadly after trying the above method "sudo  pkill 32194", the "pgrep -l a | grep 32194" still shows the process.  sudo pkill doesn't kill it :/